# Convert String to Integer with parseInt

Tags: javascript

```
        var str = '0.5';
        var int = 0.1;
```

I would like the output of `str + int` to equal `0.6`

Using `alert(parseInt(str) + int);` did not yield these results.

Comment: Well, what happens when you do `alert(parseInt('0.5'))`? Now, how does parseInt differ from `parseFloat`? In any case, whenever using `parseInt` (where it applies), also specify the radix.

Comment: Seriously? You're wondering why you don't get the expected ***fractional*** result when you're using ***integer*** math?

Comment: I don't understand why I get downvoted when I'm trying to learn to program properly and I gain an insightful understanding by getting an answer. I may not be as logical/smart as you, but believe me when I say I aspire to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`parseInt` parses your string into an integer:

```
> parseInt('0.5', 10);
0
```

Since you want a float, use `parseFloat()`:

```
> parseFloat('0.5');
0.5
```

Comment: `+'0.5' + 0.1` ... tada! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to convert strings to numbers (integers are whole numbers, which isn't what you want!) in JavaScript (doesn't need jQuery)

By far the easiest is to use the unary + operator:

```
var myNumber = +myString;
```

or

```
alert( (+str) + int );
```

Also you shouldn't use "int" as a variable name; it's a bad habit (it's often a keyword, and as I said, 0.1 is *not* an int)

Answer (score 0):

The correct would be using `parseFloat`:

```
var result = parseFloat(str) + int;
alert( result ); // 0.6
```